# Setup for module based Software

Tags: installation, wix, setup-project, bootstrapper

I have developed a `Modulebase Software` that is splitt up in two parts.
The first part is `Service(BaseSoftware)` and the part are `some Modules` that can be add to this Service.

**State Now:**
I already have created a Wix Setup for the Service(BaseSoftware). But now I need to install the modules. Each Module should have an own MSI-Setup.

**Problem:**
Before I can install a module the BaseSoftware has to be installed.

**Solution:**
I thought I could have custom action in the Modules Setup that asks the System if the BaseSoftware is already installed. If not just start the Setup for the BaseSoftware, and then continue with the modules Setup.

But I don't really know what is the best practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Service installer, write a registry value that indicates your service is installed - here is an example that writes the install directory to the registry (you should customize the key)

```
    <Component Id="ServiceRegistryKeys" Directory="InstallLocation" Permanent='yes'>
        <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\My Company\My Service">
            <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="InstallPath" Value="[INSTALLDIR]" KeyPath="yes" />
        </RegistryKey>
    </Component>
```

In the module installers, you can check for that key, and fail if not present:

```
    <!-- Require Service to be installed already -->
    <Property Id="SERVICEPATH">
        <RegistrySearch Id="ServicePath" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\My Company\My Service" Name="InstallPath" Type="raw" />
    </Property>
    <Condition Message='The Service is not installed. Please install the Service first, and then this module.'><![CDATA[Installed OR (SERVICEPATH <> "")]]></Condition>
```

Make sure you use the same registry key

Comment: Your Solution sounds great, but BaseSoftware Setup does not create a registry entry, I do it exaxt your way

Comment: Okay, I found the Problem, It wrote the entry to the X64 registry

Comment: My example works in my installers as it appears, however i do have my installers set to be 64bit only using the the platform attribute of my Package element: <Package Platform="x64"

Comment: Could you provide a complete working example ? Maybe on Github ? The stuff I made yesterday didn't work properly

Comment: [Simple working example](https://gitlab.com/chris2/wix-toolset-examples/tree/master/RequireServiceBeforeModules) - you need the wix toolset tools on your path, run the build.cmd which generates 2 msi's - try to run the module install - it will fail. Then run the service install completely, and run the module install again - it will continue